# Errors in Unity when building the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gradle, build.gradle, build-error

I am making an android game in Unity 2020.3.30f, scripting backend is IL2CPP, target architectures ARMv7 and ARM64,building a .aab file (for google play), and 3 errors appear:
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Error 1:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:bundleReleaseResources'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  C:\Users\Semejnyj\Desktop\edness run 2\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\processReleaseManifest\bundle-manifest\AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
  


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Error 2:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.30f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.30f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:bundleReleaseResources'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  C:\Users\Semejnyj\Desktop\edness run 2\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\processReleaseManifest\bundle-manifest\AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
  


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :unityLibrary
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
47 actionable tasks: 26 executed, 21 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <762caba6f98a4d7e9d56f7b5bd6e35d6>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <68089899e4c84456bfc1de3436accf4a>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Error 3:

```
Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :unityLibrary
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Configure project :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.


> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseSources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:bundleReleaseResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
47 actionable tasks: 26 executed, 21 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Is it related to Google Ads?What should I do? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your error, but I had some errors while I was using Google Ads and where Target API wasn't level 30 (at player setting=> others), it was lower.
And actually, Target API Should be 30 and above if you are planning to release it on the Play store.